# JAVA execute function on Centos with command line

Tags: java, centos

I'm really beginner in Java. I have some .jar file which has classes and functions such as on screenshot below[image].

I want to execute 'podpiszDokumentDowolnymCertyfikatem'.

I'm trying something like this:

```
java -cp podpisKwalifikowany.jar PodpisKwalifikowany.podpiszDokumentDowolnymCertyfikatem('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
```

but getting error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

java -cp podpisKwalifikowany.jar PodpisKwalifikowany .podpiszDokumentDowolnymCertyfikatem
return

```
Error: Could not find or load main class PodpisKwalifikowany.podpiszDokumentDowo                                                                                                                                                             lnymCertyfikatem
```

java -cp podpisKwalifikowany.jar PodpisKwalifikowany()
but again:

```
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Anyone can help me? 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `PodpisKwalifikowany` is an executable class (a class with `main`), you can use the following syntax to run it:

```
java -cp podpisKwalifikowany.jar PodpisKwalifikowany
```

If `PodpisKwalifikowany` is not an executable class, you will have to write an executable class wherein you will have to instantiate `PodpisKwalifikowany` and then call the menthods on the instance.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class PodpisKwalifikowany

Comment: Sure, my file have name podpisKwalifikowany.jar, but in PodpisKwalifikowanyClass don't have main

Comment: I'm updated first post with screens from PodpisKwalifikowanyClass